# How do I get the coordinates of a UIButton that is in an array?

Tags: ios, position, coordinates

Generally for a button you can just do

```
int x = myButton.frame.origin.x;
```

But if it's a button in an array, I'm not sure. I've tried this

```
id myArrayElement = [myArray objectAtIndex:2];
int x = myArrayElement.frame.origin.x;
```

But this doesn't work. The `objectAtIndex:2` is a `UIButton`.

Comment: how do you add your buttons into array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should check `isKindOfClass:` it's a good way to check its class.

```
id myArrayElement = [myArray objectAtIndex:2];
if ([myArrayElement isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)myArrayElement;
    int x = btn.frame.origin.x;
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! Although it seems like I don't need the if statement.. it seems just UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)myArrayElement; is the magic line I needed, although maybe I'm missing something. Also sidenote, on line 2 it should be lowercase "class".

Comment: @lettsss but its a good way to check its class if you don't know how much different element are there in your array. sometimes if it belongs to another class then your app will crash that's why. otherwise no issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are loosing the type of `UIButton` when you define `myArrayElement` as id, try changing it to `UIButton` myArrayElement, or if myArray is an array of `UIButtons`, simply put it all on one line:

```
int x = [myArray objectAtIndex:2].frame.origin.x;
```